# Spring boot actuator write trace endpoint info into a file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Any pointers on how can I log the information shown in the /trace endpoint into a file(logfile) my use case is that  I want to log all the request and response info into a log file using actuator, that way I have to write minimum logging related code into my application code . I searched for the documentation but could not find any reference. even search over the internet does not provide any relevant help.

Thanks,

pchetri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the first answer comes into my mind is to use **web filter**.
Refer to this post [Spring Boot - How to log all requests and responses with exceptions in single place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl/39181445), I think this can be easily done by doing the similar work like `/trace` in Actuator.

According to Spring Boot official document [Tracing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-tracing.html), another way is to create your own `TraceRepository` and log each request and response.

Hope this helps to you!