# Logging all request and responses using Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and REST services using `@RestController`. I want to log all requests and responses with a payload. How can I do this using `Spring Boot Actuator`? When I using:

```
    @Bean
    public ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
        ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter();
        loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
        loggingFilter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        loggingFilter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return loggingFilter;
    }
```

I get only Requests, but not Responses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - How to log all requests and responses with exceptions in single place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl)

Answer (score 1):

See baeldung [Spring – Log Incoming Requests](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) guide, specifically the 5th section [Spring Built-In Request Logging](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging#spring-built-in-request-logging)

**TL;DR**
If you are using Spring Boot you can configure that easily like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

**General note:** In production application you should be careful logging payloads as they may contain private user data that should not be logged from privacy considerations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `addInterceptors` method of `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer {

  override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor())
  }
}
```

And [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) is good example for interceptor.

**UPDATED**

You can override the Spring `LoggingFilter`

```
public class CustomLoggingFilter extends LoggingFilter
{
     @Override
     protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
     {
          super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
     }
}

@Configuration
public Config {
    @Bean
    public CustomLoggingFilter loggingFilter()
    {
        return new CustomLoggingFilter();
    }
}
```

Not sure about your format, but you can try to use:

```
logging:
  level: 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor: debug //response
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer: debug //request
```

Comment: I try like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging But It dont work for me, payload don't logging!

Comment: And your example don't have logging of payload. Without payload It make easy!

Comment: I saw it. It use  `DispatcherServlet`, but I using `Spring Boot`

Comment: When providing an answer please make sure it answers the requirements in the question and not similar (but different) requirements (your solution does not log payload, and the provided link does not use Spring Boot)