# Spring MVC: log all requests, even the resource not founds

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I log all requests in Spring MVC, even the resource not founds ones?

I guess interceptors can not log resource not found requests. What do you suggest?

Comment: Look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461617/get-xml-from-httpservletrequest-and-use-into-endpoint/56301828?noredirect=1#comment99290019_56301828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using implementation of `javax.servlet.Filter`?

`Filter` in contrary to Spring's interceptor is part of a Java's standard and is executed by the servlet container for each incoming HTTP request..

Spring MVC use exactly one servlet and that is `DispatcherServlet` which, as the name suggest, disptach received request to correct controller which process the request futher.

Spring even provide few concrete implementations of `Filter` that can log incoming request for you such as: `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` or `ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter`.

You can choose one of the above implementations or implement `Filter` interface by yourself - whatever you decide, by using `Filter` you should be able to log every single request received by your servlet container.