# In Spring how to audit endpoint communication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, auditing

My intent is to audit the data exchange through the endpoints of my application. I wanna retrieve the json exchanged throught the endpoints and store it in the database. For storing the json data I will use Javes (https://javers.org/) but I still need to figure out how to obtain the endpoint data.

Comment: Write an interceptor may be to catch the request and response by implementing `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write interceptor to do additional processing of requests and responses flowing through your application.
If you are using `spring` it is very easy to implement. Here is an example:

```
@Component
public class RestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

 @Override
 public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
  ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
  traceRequest(request, body);
  ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
  traceResponse(response);
  return response;
 }

 private void traceRequest(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws IOException {
   //track request here
 }


 private void traceResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    //track response here
 }

}
```

Now register it with your rest template

```
restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new RestInterceptor ()));
```

Comment: Where do I configure the following " Register ClientHttpRequestInterceptor with RestTemplate" in a short spring boot application. I am following an example here: howtodoinjava.com/spring-restful/clienthttprequestinterceptor

Comment: Follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33744875/3503187) and you can also check logback-access to log requests coming to your application. The example in the answer logs request and responses going from your application.