# How can I log all REST calls?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, logging, jersey

Inside of the debugger I can see

```
JerseyWebTarget { http://host.com/service/method }
```

and I see how it builds the parameters and then executes the service.method(parms) call.
Can I somehow log the call so that I get the full URL like

```
http://host.com/service/method?id=5
```

and also with more complex parameters like a big JSON file that I transfer to the service?

Comment: Please post the code that you have

Comment: you can create your own [Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) to log request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - How to log all requests and responses with exceptions in single place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl)

Answer (score 0):

Inbuilt spring provides a filter for this purpose. Add below bean to configuration file.

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    return loggingFilter;
}
```

Also **change log level of `org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` to `DEBUG`**.

Comment: I added this Bean to my config. I also put the log level to DEBUG. I am running through a service method then where I have 
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class); It does not help. I do not see the call.