# how to get controller class name in interceptors for logging

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, logging

In my springboot application, we are logging controller requests/responses using the `org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and `org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper`. Refer below link for the sample code .

**CustomLoggingFilter :**

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023374/1958669

There is a `interceptor` present in the application. Now the problem is while logging its only the interceptor name coming in className . So, for getting the actual controller name , I tried getting classname in interceptor . But that gives `org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper`.

**CustomWebMvcConfig :**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CustomLogInterceptor());
    }
}
```

**CustomLogInterceptor :**

```
public class CustomLogInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomLogInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception{
        //Some operation
    }
}
```

Getting logs in below format:

> time="2019-03-18T09:59:51,001Z", thread="[o-auto-1exec-]" ,class=“a.b.c.CustomLoggingFilter           ",message=“Payload_1“
>
> time="2019-03-18T09:59:51,001Z", thread="[o-auto-1-xec-1]" ,class=“a.b.c.CustomLoggingFilter           ",message=“Payload_2“"

My Question is how to get the actual ControllerClass name in logs instead of the LoggingFilterClass (one which uses the `org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper`)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: Im getting logs in the below format ie classname is always CustomLoggingFilter , rather it should be actual controller name.

`time="2019-03-18T09:59:51,001Z",thread="[o-auto-1-exec-1]",class=“a.b.c.CustomLoggingFilter           ",message=“Payload_1“
time="2019-03-18T09:59:51,001Z",thread="[o-auto-1-exec-1]",class=“a.b.c.CustomLoggingFilter           ",message=“Payload_2“`

Comment: Are you going to use this for logging purposes?

Comment: Yes, for logging only.

Comment: Then I suggest your best shot is to use an Aspect to do what you want.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex : you have any reference links for aspect springboot rest api logging ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
String controllerName = handlerMethod.getBeanType().getSimpleName().replace("Controller", "");
```

Or if you want to print the URI:

```
request.getRequestURI();
```

I think you can't change the logger as you don't know who would be the controller.