# How to list REST API calls made to server

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, tomcat, catalina

I have a Spring Boot backend application and I'd like to list all the REST API calls made by clients to my application. 
I'm running my app in Tomcat/nginx.

Comment: From list you mean log, right? [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl)

Comment: Check this answer. It has complete code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164562/3073945

Comment: @NikolayHristov yes thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1** (Actuator):
You can track last 100 request using Spring Boot Actuator. Here is the way to do this :

**Add the maven dependency**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Edit the **application.properties** and add the following line:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

After running your spring boot application, now you can track the latest 100 http requests by calling this url: 
*http://localhost:8070/actuator/httptrace*

**Way 2** (Aspect):

But you can also get the log using Aspect.

It provide you some amazing annotation  like: @Before ,  @AfterReturning, @AfterThrowing etc.

Here `@Before` log the **url,request parameters**, `@AfterReturning` log the response parameters and `@AfterThrowing` log the error with message, You may not don't need all endpoints log, so here have some filters based on package.

To implement this feature using aspects check [this anawer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164562/3073945)