# Spring-boot - not finding httptrace at /actuator on HAL browser

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I included actuator and hal browser depndencies in my pom.xml aslo i have put configuration management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* in application.properties , but I am not finding httptrace in /actautor , please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I am able to see metrics and other options.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you should add HttpTraceRepository bean. Simple way - write this in any @Configuration class:

```
 @Bean
    public HttpTraceRepository httpTrace() {
        return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
    }
```

Of course aplication.config shoult have management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* or management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,httptrace if you don't want to expose redundant endpoints.

Comment: For me, it only shows the header. It doesn't show the body.