# Spring CommonsRequestLoggingFilter workaround to log request/response payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a RESTful API using JSON as request/reply format and I would like to log the payload sent by the client and the response sent by the API.

*(Spring Boot version defined in my pom.xml is 2.2.1.RELEASE)*

Spring provides a very conveniant Filter to do so :

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
  CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
  filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
  filter.setIncludePayload(true);
  filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
  filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);

  return filter;
}
```

But it doesn't work : no payload is logged !

If I dig into the code the interesting part in the extended class `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal`:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

  [...]

  if (isIncludePayload() && isFirstRequest && !(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
    requestToUse = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request, getMaxPayloadLength());
  }

  [...]
}
```

It uses `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` to workaround the fact the payload is a Stream and so can be consumed only once.

The construct inits a ByteArrayOutputStream to cache the payload:

```
public ContentCachingRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, int contentCacheLimit) {
  super(request);
  this.cachedContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream(contentCacheLimit);
  this.contentCacheLimit = contentCacheLimit;
}
```

But it doesn't copy the content of the stream into the var `cachedContent` except if you call the method `writeRequestParametersToCachedContent` (via `getParameterValues` for example) which is never the case and so the stream remains to 0.

Questions:

1. Why the hell the stream isn't copied in the constructor ?
2. Is there a workaround to do not reimplement everything just because `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` is buggy ?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43155103/592355: "**Don't forget** to change log level of `org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` to `DEBUG`."

Comment: ..and "**Note** that it does not log the responses, only the requests."

Comment: The log level is ok as I see some logging (i.e. Before request [POST /policies/test]) but no payload.
It's ok if it logs only the request, it's half of the job done ;)