# ContentCachingRequestWrapper only captures POST request with Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to intercept all incoming HTTP requests and process the body attached to these requests in my Spring MVC (not Spring Boot) app. To implement this "inbound-interceptor", I am using Spring's [HandlerInterceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) interface. Once the request is intercepted, I am trying to retrieve the body as follows:

```java
ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
Map<String, String[]> params = requestWrapper.getParameterMap();
byte[] body = requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
```

Referring to this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging), the limitations of trying to extract the body this way are:

1. Content-type of the request must be `x-www-form-urlencoded`
2. Method-type must be `POST`

For the application I am building, I cannot enforce either of these constraints as the calls come from heterogeneous sources beyond my control. Is there some way to override this behavior to allow extraction of the body for requests not supported by default? Or, alternatively, is there another approach to performing this task?

P.S. I am performing logging + some custom processing on the body. So solutions such as the ones mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl) are not too helpful

Comment: What do you mean by "processing"? Do you want to change the body before Spring MVC processes this changed body?

Comment: @SvenDöring No changes to the body. I have a couple of custom logging classes that I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Logbook? https://github.com/zalando/logbook Works with pure Spring.

Their Default Log Writer looks promising: https://github.com/zalando/logbook/blob/main/logbook-core/src/main/java/org/zalando/logbook/DefaultHttpLogWriter.java

And you may just want to extend this class to log to all Loggers you want.
You can even do something completely different with the request besides logging.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will give it a try. Although for now, I have found a combination of `OncePerRequestFilter` and `ContentCachingWrappers` that works just fine to capture everything required from the request (https://github.com/taabishm2/Spring-Inbound-Interceptor) without requiring any dedicated libraries to be used