# Log raw request body before deserialization in Spring Boot REST controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

Given the following, kind of basic, REST controller in Spring Boot:

```java
@RestController
public class NotificationController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/notification")
    public void handleNotification(@RequestBody @Valid NotificationRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getMessage());
    }
}
```

One requirement is to log the incoming request body **before** deserializing it to a `NotificationRequest`. We'd like to have a trace, e.g. if the request is not well-formed. My first idea was to use the `HttpServletRequest` directly but then I would lose the validation and automatic deserialization.

```java
public void handleNotification(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
  // ...
}
```

Is there some mechanism to log the incoming "raw" request body for this particular endpoint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - How to log all requests and responses with exceptions in single place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl)

Comment: The linked question and answers provide a lot of information and are kind of helpful. In my case, however, I only need the "raw" request for this specific controller method.