# Sporadic: REST service gets triggered multiple times even if in DevTools the network call is triggered only once

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, angular6, httpclient

I have an microservice application where we use

- Angular 6 (Client)
- Java 8 (Server)
- PostgreSQL (DB)
  The network tab on devtools shows single entry, so I added logs at each level (Filter, Controller, Ps). The log4j logs shows multiple threads created for accessing same query/function, hence delaying the response time.
  Does anyone have any idea?

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nVJJ.png)

I have tried with adding shareReplay() to the http service to always have single network call  but it is not feasible for me as user can trigger the same nw call again and in that case it won't work.

Also checked my Filter configuration in spring boot, there does not seem any issue as the filter is annotated with @Component and no other extra configuration logic is applied there.

There is no multiple subscriptions of the observable that calls the http network call as the UI is blocked until the user gets response from the DB.

Comment: the logs shows that there are 2 requests, and there is 53 seconds between them, I think this is coming from outside, you can enable request log https://stackoverflow.com/a/43155103/175554 and see.